# Trigger is not getting fired in SSIS

Tags: sql-server, ssis, triggers

I have the following after insert trigger:

```
ALTER TRIGGER [dbo].[Add_IDBrg]
ON [dbo].[Groupe_Brg]
AFTER INSERT
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    UPDATE [dbo].[Groupe_Brg]
    SET  [IdBrg_Groupe] = (SELECT MAX(IdBrg_Groupe)+1 FROM [dbo].[Groupe_Brg])
    FROM Inserted i
    WHERE i.[id] = [dbo].[Groupe_Brg].[Id]
END
```

When I do a normal insert like :

```
INSERT INTO [dbo].[Groupe_Brg] ([IdBrg_Groupe], [Checksum_grp], [SK_Groupe]) 
VALUES (0, 12355, 1112), (0, 12355, 1113);
```

The trigger can update my `[IdBrg_Groupe]` normally, but when I execute my inserts with "OLE DB Destination" component in SSIS, it doesn't work (`[IdBrg_Groupe]` is NULL) despite adding the "FIRE_TRIGGERS" in fastloadOptions.

What's the problem?

Comment: `SELECT MAX(IdBrg_Groupe)+1` sound like a design flaw anyway; why are you not using a sequence? This could easily suffer race conditions. Also, is it planned than when you insert multiple rows they all get the same ID?

Comment: @Larnu, I want to insert the same [IdBrg_Groupe] than [Checksum_grp], is it possible to do that using a sequence?